# WireGuard Hub and Spoke with subnet sharing

Tags: vpn, firewall, wireguard, asus

I'm a quite happy OpenVPN user who, for security and performance reasons, decided to switch everything to Wireguard.

The main target is to be able to access the office private lan from outside. Both office router and outside peers are behind firewalls so I decided to adopt a Hub and Spoke configuration. The hub is on a linux cloud VPS with public IP.
The configuration is the same I currently adopt with OpenVPN: there is a server accessible from the internet and several clients that can communicate with each other when connected to the VPN. One of these is a router that expose its private LAN to the other clients.

I use the office router as WG client with VPN Fusion (it's a ASUS RT-AX92U) and I'm able to see all the other computers, both in the VPN and in the private LAN.

```
VPN address range   = 10.10.10.0/24
LAN address range   = 192.168.51.0/24
router address LAN  = 192.168.51.1
router address VPN  = 10.10.10.3
wireguard hub       = 10.10.10.1
peer A              = 10.10.10.4
peer B              = 10.10.10.5
```

The main issue is that I cannot connect directly to the router from the VPN. Both 10.10.10.3 and 192.168.51.1 are not responding. Also ping doesn't work. I don't understand if it is due to the firewall or to the WG configuration. With OpenVPN everything works fine.
Of course the router is accessible from the private LAN.

I found similar questions but I already tried the suggested solutions without success. There is something I'm just not getting...

Please find here below the configuration file for the hub:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.10.10.1/32
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = ************
PreUp = iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i wg0 -j MARK --set-mark 0x30
PreUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -o wg0 -m mark --mark 0x30 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -t mangle -D PREROUTING -i wg0 -j MARK --set-mark 0x30
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING ! -o wg0 -m mark --mark 0x30 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = ************
PresharedKey = ************
AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.3/32, 192.168.51.0/24

[Peer]
PublicKey = ************
PresharedKey = ************
AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.4/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = ************
PresharedKey = ************
AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.5/32
```

The configuration file for the router

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.10.10.3/32
PrivateKey = ********

[Peer]
PublicKey = ********
PresharedKey = ********
AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.0/24
Endpoint = cloudIP:51820
```

and the configuration file for Peer B (Peer A is the same)

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.10.10.5/32
PrivateKey = ********

[Peer]
PublicKey = ********
PresharedKey = ********
AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.0/24, 192.168.51.0/24
Endpoint = cloudIP:51820
```

---

EDIT 1

After the thorough analysis of @Robbie I focused more on the firewall setup. Indeed adapting the hub wg0.conf file as he proposed works as before, so I removed the MASQUERADE lines and added the ip-forward line, restoring the ip-forward = 0 at system level.

The I run a traceroute command on Peer A activating also a tcpdump on hub and I obtained the following result:

on Peer A

```
C:\Users\inter> TRACERT.EXE 192.168.51.55
Tracing route to 192.168.51.55 over a maximum of 30 hops
1    23 ms    23 ms    23 ms  10.10.10.1
2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
3    42 ms    40 ms    40 ms  192.168.51.55
Trace complete.
```

on hub

```
[root@remoto3 wireguard]# tcpdump -tttnei wg0
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wg0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
 00:00:00.000000 ip: 10.10.10.4 > 192.168.51.55: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 4540, length 72
 00:00:00.000038 ip: 10.10.10.4 > 192.168.51.55: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 4540, length 72
 00:00:00.019062 ip: 192.168.51.55 > 10.10.10.4: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 4540, length 72
 00:00:00.000023 ip: 192.168.51.55 > 10.10.10.4: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 4540, length 72
 00:00:00.023966 ip: 10.10.10.4 > 192.168.51.55: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 4541, length 72
 00:00:00.000022 ip: 10.10.10.4 > 192.168.51.55: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 4541, length 72
 00:00:00.018760 ip: 192.168.51.55 > 10.10.10.4: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 4541, length 72
 00:00:00.000021 ip: 192.168.51.55 > 10.10.10.4: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 4541, length 72
 00:00:00.021823 ip: 10.10.10.4 > 192.168.51.55: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 4542, length 72
 00:00:00.000020 ip: 10.10.10.4 > 192.168.51.55: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 4542, length 72
 00:00:00.018592 ip: 192.168.51.55 > 10.10.10.4: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 4542, length 72
 00:00:00.000021 ip: 192.168.51.55 > 10.10.10.4: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 4542, length 72
 00:00:00.442107 ip: 10.10.10.4.netbios-ns > 192.168.51.55.netbios-ns: UDP, length 50
 00:00:00.000135 ip: 10.10.10.1 > 10.10.10.4: ICMP host 192.168.51.55 unreachable - admin prohibited filter, length 86
 00:00:01.503801 ip: 10.10.10.4.netbios-ns > 192.168.51.55.netbios-ns: UDP, length 50
 00:00:00.000089 ip: 10.10.10.1 > 10.10.10.4: ICMP host 192.168.51.55 unreachable - admin prohibited filter, length 86
 00:00:01.515731 ip: 10.10.10.4.netbios-ns > 192.168.51.55.netbios-ns: UDP, length 50
 00:00:00.000121 ip: 10.10.10.1 > 10.10.10.4: ICMP host 192.168.51.55 unreachable - admin prohibited filter, length 86
 00:10:07.780807 ip: 10.10.10.4 > 192.168.51.1: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 4543, length 40
 00:00:00.000106 ip: 10.10.10.4 > 192.168.51.1: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 4543, length 40
 00:00:04.668951 ip: 10.10.10.4 > 192.168.51.1: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 4544, length 40
 00:00:00.000044 ip: 10.10.10.4 > 192.168.51.1: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 4544, length 40
 00:00:42.525787 ip: 10.10.10.4 > 10.10.10.1: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 4545, length 40
 00:00:00.000148 ip: 10.10.10.1 > 10.10.10.4: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 4545, length 40
 00:00:01.019225 ip: 10.10.10.4 > 10.10.10.1: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 4546, length 40
 00:00:00.000073 ip: 10.10.10.1 > 10.10.10.4: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 4546, length 40
 00:00:14.268544 ip: 10.10.10.4 > 10.10.10.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 4547, length 40
 00:00:00.000170 ip: 10.10.10.4 > 10.10.10.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 4547, length 40
 00:00:04.684129 ip: 10.10.10.4 > 10.10.10.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 4548, length 40
 00:00:00.000040 ip: 10.10.10.4 > 10.10.10.3: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 4548, length 40
```

It seems actually there is something that is filtering the traffic, I suspect it is the router firewall, even though its ip address doesn't appear clearly in this output, but I already tried to relax it without success...

---

Edit2

I run the test, suggested by @Robbie in the comments, from one of the peers on the WG network and, as expected, the router filters everything.

```
[root@peer ~]$ nmap -Pn 10.10.10.3
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-12-11 09:00 CET
Nmap scan report for 10.10.10.3
Host is up.
All 1000 scanned ports on 10.10.10.3 are in ignored states.
Not shown: 1000 filtered tcp ports (no-response)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 201.47 seconds
```

It's definitely a problem related to the router firewall and the wireguard setup is correct. I'll work on it.

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid question but I can see where you're adding your masquerade rules, but is ip forwarding enabled on your hub?

Comment: It's a good question. Short answer: yes. Ip forwarding is enabled on the hub directly in the sysctl.conf file. Globally the VPN works well, the main issue is that the router is not accessible from the VPN even though it does its job exposing properly the private LAN.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, this is my understanding of your setup.

[image]

I used network namespaces to build a toy model of your network and deploy your config (unfortunately I didn't have time to build it to scale or to paint it)

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo true

sudo ./newHub.sh wan
sudo ./newHub.sh lan

sudo ./newHost.sh router
sudo ./newHost.sh lanA
sudo ./newHost.sh lanB

sudo ./hostToHub.sh router eth0 192.168.51.1/24 lan
sudo ./hostToHub.sh lanA   eth0 192.168.51.101/24 lan
sudo ./hostToHub.sh lanB   eth0 192.168.51.102/24 lan

sudo ip netns exec router sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

sudo ip -n lanA route add default via 192.168.51.1
sudo ip -n lanB route add default via 192.168.51.1

sudo ./newHost.sh hub
sudo ./newHost.sh peerA
sudo ./newHost.sh peerB

sudo ./hostToHub.sh router wan0 172.16.0.1/24 wan
sudo ./hostToHub.sh hub    wan0 172.16.0.2/24 wan
sudo ./hostToHub.sh peerA  wan0 172.16.0.3/24 wan
sudo ./hostToHub.sh peerB  wan0 172.16.0.4/24 wan


sudo ip netns exec router wg-quick up ./wg/router/wg0.conf # 10.10.10.3
sudo ip netns exec hub    wg-quick up ./wg/hub/wg0.conf    # 10.10.10.1
sudo ip netns exec peerA  wg-quick up ./wg/peerA/wg0.conf  # 10.10.10.4
sudo ip netns exec peerB  wg-quick up ./wg/peerB/wg0.conf  # 10.10.10.5
```

Each respective `wg0.conf` matches your examples. At this stage, every wireguard peer could ping the center hub, but not each other. I didn't actually think your masquerade rules were actually doing anything, so I deleted those, and I added `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` to the wg0.conf for the hub.

Excerpt from wg/hub/wg.conf

```
PreUp = sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
PostDown = sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
```

And then everything worked perfectly.

```
[root@orobas virtopology]# traceroute 192.168.51.101 # ping to a device on the router's lan, from peerA
traceroute to 192.168.51.101 (192.168.51.101), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1)  0.541 ms  0.531 ms  0.523 ms
 2  10.10.10.3 (10.10.10.3)  0.969 ms  0.966 ms  1.039 ms
 3  192.168.51.101 (192.168.51.101)  1.041 ms  1.044 ms  1.037 ms
[root@orobas virtopology]#
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you @robbie, your chart perfectly depicts my network configuration. From your reply I understand two things: 1) WG setup seems to be right, 2) firewall directives should be checked. I'll work on it. Do you think that MASQUERADE on Hub is not necessary?

Comment: @LucaR I think I skimmed your post too quickly the first time I read it, I wrote my answer thinking that devices on the wireguard side couldn't access the router itself OR the clients on the router side. That definitely sounds like a firewall issue, the router is dropping packets that are bound for the router itself but don't originate from within the LAN, which to be fair is a totally reasonable configuration for a router. I would try `nmap -Pn 10.10.10.3` to see if it's just pings being dropped. Unfortunately I don't know anything about configuring the firewall on that router